# Download exe from url

Tags: powershell

I want to download the latest xdat.exe found on the site

```
https://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx
```

but I can not. I get the error message:

> "System.Object []" in type "System.Uri", required by the parameter "Uri". The specified method is not supported.

Anyone know why?

```
    $destfolder = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\MCAFEE $((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))"
    If(!(test-path $destfolder))
    {
          New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destfolder
    }

    $urlrootpath = "https://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx"      
    $dest = "$destfolder\xdat.exe"
    $definitionPath = (Invoke-WebRequest $urlrootpath).Links |
        Where-Object{$_.InnerText -like "*xdat.exe"} |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty href
    ForEach-Object -Process { 
       try {  
           Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $definitionPath -OutFile $dest
       } catch {            
           Write-Warning -Message "ERROR : $($_.Exception.Message)"            
       }            
    }
```

Comment: Likely means that `$definitionPath` contains multiple URL's.

Comment: do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Why not just use McAfee's management tools?

Comment: I need to run scripts at work in the evening to get the updates

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this `$definitionPath` is empty. Probably, because you first have to accept the license agreement, to see the download links on the page. However, you can access the downloads from http://download.nai.com/products/datfiles/V3DAT or http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/english/intel.

Also `Foreach-Object` requires an `InputObject` to be effective. Currently there is non. Add the parameter `-InputObject $definitionPath` or add a `|` in the previous line and replace `$definitionPath` with `$_` within the `-Process` ScriptBlock.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found how to do it, the only problem is that it takes me the 3 .exe file and I want the most recent file ... Is it possible?

```
$urlrootpath = "http://download.nai.com/products/licensed/superdat/nai/French/"       
$definitionPath = (Invoke-WebRequest $urlrootpath).Links |
    Where-Object{$_.InnerText -like "*xdat.exe"} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty href |
ForEach-Object -Process { 
   try {  
       $dest = "$destfolder\$_" 
       Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlrootpath/$_ -OutFile $dest
   } catch {            
       Write-Warning -Message "ERROR : $($_.Exception.Message)"            
   }            
}
```